# Need to refresh page first time to display cookies in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, cookies, struts2

I am using struts2 and jsp for my website. When I am trying to display the cookie on the first main jsp page the cookie is not displayed. When I refresh the page the cookie is display. Similar thing happens when I login in and cookie is set in action class. After redirecting to another page where I try to display the cookie it does not display. I need to refresh again to make it visible.

Below is my code to display cookie.

```
<%
    Cookie cookieee[]=request.getCookies();
    if(cookieee!=null)
    for(Cookie co:cookieee)
    {
        if(co.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("cust"))
            out.println(co.getValue());
    }
%>
```

The problem what I feel is request.getCookies() is returning null value for the main page. And When logging in it is returning the previous value of cookies and not the updated value.

How I can display value with refreshing?

Comment: Do not use scriptlets :(

Comment: Agree... You should initialize the cookies with the controller and than relate to the variable in the jsp